# BackgroundWorker vs. Async/Await

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async

I am new to C# development and wish to create a more responsive UI. In my preliminary research, I have seen two methods for achieving this:

1. Multi-threading in conjunction with the BackgroundWorker class.
2. The newer Async/Await modifiers.

Does newer mean better? What's the difference between the two methods? If I wish to create a new project, how do I choose which method to go with?

EDIT: Maybe I should specify. I am creating a Windows Forms application, where all necessary data will be saved/loaded on the local disk. I will also be communicating with several USB devices.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will be able to accomplish your task using `BackgroundWorker`. It is a well known class, and many people have used it.

The new C# 5 `async` and `await` keywords basically just make it easier to write readable asynchronous code. There may be fewer tutorials and examples of how to accomplish various tasks with these keywords rather than `BackgroundWorker`.

Unless you need to use an older version of C#, I suggest learning how to use `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 15):

The `async` and `await` keywords will not make your application more responsive on their own. They simply make the calling and handling of methods that return `Task` objects more convenient. In order to make `async`/`await` actually use background threads, you will need to combine with the usage of things like:

- `Task.Start()` - Starts a given task using the `TaskScheduler`.
- PLINQ - Execute a series of operations in parallel, returns a Task.
- `TaskCompletionSource` - A custom way to handle async tasks. One place I used this was to handle events coming from a `WebBrowser` control.
- Other `async` methods, such as many of the functions in the Win 8 API.

In other words, `async`/`await` is an extension of the **[Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx)**.  You can find a large host of information, including many samples, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

The `BackgroundWorker` is a WinForms component that creates 1 background thread using the [Event-Based Asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx), and you can populate the work done on this background thread with your own code in the `DoWork` event handler. In general, **Microsoft no longer recommends using this pattern** (see the bottom of the page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx)), though if you are familiar with it already it may still be a simple option.

Another option not mentioned, is the [Reactive Extensions for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).  This is another great framework for adding responsiveness to your apps.

Comment: When you say Win 8 API, does that imply the Async features aren't as well-supported on Windows 7 (my target platform)?

Comment: Hi Robert, the Win 8 .NET API (for "Metro"-style apps) using async and await heavily for everything from File I/O to showing dialog boxes.  In other .NET components, for example, FileStream, you can also use async/await with methods like Stream.ReadAsync.  So there is some support outside of Win 8, too.

Comment: Great, and thanks for the updated links too! Very helpful.

Comment: I don't see anything on that page indicating that `BackgroundWorker`, specifically, is recommended against.

Comment: I also recommend the reading of [Async VS BackgroundWorker](http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/caolan/async/q/stackoverflow/12414601/async-await-vs-backgroundworker) and the [series of blog posts](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) about **Concurrent programming in C#** of Stephen Clearly, the author of the omonymous book published by O'Reilly.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that `async`-`await` is much more flexible than `BackgroundWorker`. And if you want to do something that fits `BackgroundWorker`, you can do it with `async`-`await` too, with more readable and more type-safe code.

Because of that, I think you should prefer using `async`-`await` over `BackgroundWorker`.